# mysql id exists in this table or that table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am querying a mysql db.  I have 3 tables:

Officials

```
id | first | last
------------------
1  | jim   | smith
2  | john   | Doe
3  | larry  | toad
4  | Dave   | Charles
```

Games

```
id | gm_date    | league | REF | UMP
--------------------------------
1  | 2015-03-27 | 1      |   4 | 
2  | 2015-03-28 | 1      |     | 
3  | 2015-03-29 | 1      |     | 
4  | 2015-04-01 | 1      |     | 2
```

Events

```
id | date       | league | off | 
--------------------------------
1  | 2015-03-27 | 1      | 1   | 
2  | 2015-03-28 | 1      |     | 
3  | 2015-03-29 | 1      |     | 
4  | 2015-04-01 | 1      |     |
```

I want to query the query both the games table and the events table to see if the id is there for a given date.  If it is in one or both I would like to return true.

Here is my query so far but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
SELECT id , first , last
                    FROM officials AS o
                    WHERE o.id = 4 &&
                    EXISTS (

                    SELECT *
                    FROM games AS g
                    WHERE g.REF = o.id && g.gm_date = '2015-03-27' && g.league = 1
                    ) ||
                    EXISTS (

                    SELECT *
                    FROM events as e
                    WHERE e.off = o.id && e.date = '2015-03-27' && e.league = 1
                    )
```

It is returning all of the ids for the date not the Id that I am requesting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I hope I am describing well enough?

Comment: Poor Charles has no id :(

Comment: `FROM officials AS o` should be `FROM officials o` since you're identifying a table abbreviation, not a column identifier. -- or does that actually work in both cases?

Comment: I am not sure how to edit the original question but, I have made the changes and removed the AS.  It made no difference same response.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT 
    id , 
    first , 
    last
FROM officials AS o
WHERE o.id = 4 
AND
(
    SELECT 
        NULL 
    FROM 
        games AS g
    WHERE 
        g.REF = o.id 
        AND g.gm_date = '2015-03-27' 
        AND g.league = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        NULL
    FROM 
        events as e
    WHERE 
        e.off = o.id 
        AND e.date = '2015-03-27' 
        AND e.league = 1
)
```

Comment: Thank you!!  Not exactly but close enough to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:  Seems odd that you're not also looking at UMP in games table.
I used a join over exists incase you need to return additional data about the game or event.

```
SELECT o.id, o.first, o.last
FROM officials o
LEFT JOIN Games g
  on g.Ref = O.id
 and g.gm_date = '2015-03-27'
 and g.league = 1
LEFT JOIN Events e
  on e.Off = O.Id
 and e.league = 1
 and e.date = '2015-03-27'
GROUP BY o.id, o.first, o.last
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want all officials with id 4 where a corresponding row exists in `games` or in `events`. If that's the case, then you
need parenthesis around your exists conditions because without the parenthesis the query returns all rows where the official id is 4 and a corresponding row exists in `games` plus all rows where the official (with any id) has a corresponding row in `events`

```
SELECT id , first , last
FROM officials AS o
WHERE o.id = 4 &&
(
    EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM games AS g
        WHERE g.REF = o.id && g.gm_date = '2015-03-27' && g.league = 1
    ) || EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM events as e
        WHERE e.off = o.id && e.date = '2015-03-27' && e.league = 1
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're being bitten by the order of precedence between the **`AND`** and **`OR`** logical operators.

```
SELECT  0 AND 1  OR 1
     , (0 AND 1) OR 1
     ,  0 AND (1 OR 1)
```

The addition of parens around AND/OR conditions allow you explicitly specify the order of precedence you want them evaluated.

Answer (score -1):

This is the query that seems to be working.

```
   SELECT 
       id , 
       first , 
       last
   FROM officials AS o
   WHERE o.id = 4 
   AND
   (
       SELECT 
           g.REF 
       FROM 
           games AS g
       WHERE 
           g.REF = o.id 
           AND g.gm_date = '2015-03-27' 
           AND g.league = 1
       UNION ALL
       SELECT
            e.off
       FROM 
           events as e
       WHERE 
           e.off = o.id 
           AND e.date = '2015-03-27' 
           AND e.league = 1
   )
```

Comment: You should have upvoted and selected an answer provided to you as best answer, instead you copied and pasted someone else's answer into your own new answer...